# How to use screeshotcapture in IReporter interface in Selenium using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, listener

I am using `IReporter TestNG` interface in `Selenium`, but how to capture screenshot and add in Extent Report for failed test-case ?

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for attaching failed test case screenshots to the Extent Report.

- **MyReporterClass implements IReporter interface**: It iterates over the test cases in the test suite and saves the status for each test case.

> ```
> public class MyReporterClass implements IReporter {
>
>    @Override
>    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
>       //Iterating over each suite included in the test
>       for (ISuite suite : suites) {
>          //Following code gets the suite name
>          String suiteName = suite.getName();
>          //Getting the results for the said suite
>          Map<String, ISuiteResult> suiteResults = suite.getResults();
>          for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values()) {
>             ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
>             System.out.println("Passed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
>                "' is:" + tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size());
>             System.out.println("Failed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
>                "' is:" + tc.getFailedTests().getAllResults().size());
>             System.out.println("Skipped tests for suite '" + suiteName +
>                "' is:" + tc.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size());
>          }
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

- **getScreenshot() method**: To capture the screenshot and return the destination path for the screenshot.

> ```
> public class ExtentReportsClass{
> public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws Exception {
> //below line is just to append the date format with the screenshot name to avoid duplicate names 
> String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
>  TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
>  File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
> //after execution, you could see a folder "FailedTestsScreenshots" under src folder
>  String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/FailedTestsScreenshots/"+screenshotName+dateName+".png";
>  File finalDestination = new File(destination);
>  FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
> //Returns the captured file path
>  return destination;
>   }
> }
> ```

- **@AfterMethod
  public void getResult(ItestResult result)**: It is executed after each test case execution and attaches the failed test case screenshot to Extent report.

> ```
> @AfterMethod
>  public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException{
>  if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
>  logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getName());
>  logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getThrowable());
>  //To capture screenshot path and store the path of the screenshot in the string "screenshotPath"
> String screenshotPath = ExtentReportsClass.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
>  //To add it in the extent report 
>  logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
>  }else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
>  logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
>  }
> ```

- **testng.xml file** : Include the below listener tag in the xml file .

> ```
> <listeners>
>   <listener class-name="packagename.MyReporterClass" />
> </listeners>
> ```

Comment: @arun salvi QA: did the above answer solve your problem?